# Relational Query problem :/

Tags: mysql

I seem to be having trouble querying my 'events' table which contains foreign keys.

This is what I've built up:

```
$query = 'SELECT events.*, venues.*, music_styles.* FROM events, venues, music_styles'.
    'INNER JOIN venues, music_styles v ON (events.VENUE_LOCATION = venues.ID) AND (events.MUSIC_STYLE_ID = music_styles.ID';
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

I tried to say that events.VENUE_LOCATION equals the ID of table 'venues' and that events.MUSIC_STYLE_ID equals the ID of table 'music_styles'.

This is the error I got:

> Invalid query: Not unique table/alias: 'venues'

And this is my database design:
[image]

Thanks a lot everybody :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's cut the PHP stuff, which isn't relevant. Your said,

```
SELECT events.*, venues.*, music_styles.* FROM events, venues, music_styles
       INNER JOIN venues, music_styles v ON (events.VENUE_LOCATION = venues.ID) AND (events.MUSIC_STYLE_ID = music_styles.ID
```

That's not quite right, that's not how JOINs work. It should be,

```
SELECT events.*, venues.*, music_styles.*
       FROM events
       INNER JOIN venues ON(events.VENUE_LOCATION = venues.ID)
       INNER JOIN music_styles ON(events.MUSIC_STYLE_ID = music_styles.ID)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting twice from the tables venues and music_styles, which cause your error. You have to give to each of them an unique alias (for instance: `... FROM venues AS v`).

However, your query seems really strange. You're doing some joins and cartesian products, you have unmatched parentheses, what are you trying to do exactly? Are you looking for a query like this :

```
SELECT *
  FROM events e    -- e is the alias
INNER JOIN venues v
    ON e.VENUE_LOCATION = v.ID
INNER JOIN music_styles m
    ON e.MUSIC_STYLE_ID = m.ID;
```